# Why is public read and execute required for my script to work?

Tags: linux, permissions

I have a php page that executes as script. The script is run by the user `www-data`. The script is very simply and only copies some files and checks the size using du -h. It all works but only if I put `chmod 775` on the directory. I do not understand why public needs access.

Dir

```
drwxrwsr-x   8 myuser    logging
```

Group

```
www-data : www-data logging
```

If I change the owner to `www-data` then `chmod 700` (as expected) is sufficient. However I have multiple users that need to be able to read/write/del files in that folder hence I thought creating the logging group and add all users that need access to the folder to that group would work.

How come public is required even though the group already has rwx?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't required.

I guess what's happened here is that you've added the user `www-data` to the group `logging` and that hasn't worked.

When you change groups you need to restart your webserver.  Otherwise the webserver process will never be assigned the new group.

Comment: Also, you might need to check the webserver configuration to see what group membership(s) the PHP interpreter gets. The webserver might strip out the supplemental groups for security, unless it's told that a particular group membership is needed.